# PHP preg_replace text only if in href attribute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/" title="foo">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/" alt="foo" />
</a>
```

How can I preg_replace the word **foo** only in the href attribute?

NOTE: There are multiple links on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(href="[^"]*)foo/', '$1replacement', $str);
```

Alternatively, you could use a lookbehind:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=href="[^"]*)foo/', 'replacement', $str);
```

Note that this will only work if there are no `'`-delimited attributes and no escaped `"` within your attributes.

This is why you should [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) consider to use a DOM parser, instead of manipulating HTML with regular expressions.

**Update:** Here is a proper implementation using a parser (I just picked PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, because it was the first one showing up on Google):

```
require "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html($filename);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
{
    $element->href = preg_replace('/foo/', 'replacement', $element->href);
}
```

Now `echo`ing `$html` or saving it to a file, will contain the correctly replaced HTML. (Using a DOM parser can be so easy.) ;)

Comment: or, better yet, generating the correct HTML from the very start.

Comment: Well who says, the OP is generating it?

Comment: any other plausible use-case of transforming an HTML into HTML?

Comment: I usually try not to second-guess all possible uses someone might have in mind for a particular question ^^